# SettingWithCopyWarning when using fillna() with values from current row

Tags: pandas

The following code transforms the table like this:

```
     col1  col2
0       1   3.0
1       2   4.0
2    C345   NaN
3  A56665   4.0
4   34553   NaN
5  353535   4.0

     col1   col2
0       1      3
1       2      4
2    C345   C345
3  A56665      4
4   34553  34553
5  353535      4
```

.

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'col1': [1, 2, "C345", "A56665", 34553, 353535], 'col2': [3, 4,None, 4,None, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df.col1.astype(str)

print(df)

df.col2.fillna(df.col1, inplace=True)
print(df)
```

However, I get a `SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame` when apllying this approach on large data sets. What am I doing wrong/ not in the intended way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `loc` like `df.loc[:, 'col2'].fillna(df.col1, inplace=True)`

To turn off `SettingWithCopyWarning` for a single dataframe, use

```
df.is_copy = False
```

---

Or,

```
df = df.copy()
```

Comment: still the same warning, for both cases: `df.loc[:, 'col2'].fillna(df.col1, inplace=True)`and `df.loc[:, 'col2'].fillna(df.loc[:,'col1'], inplace=True)`

Comment: Does suppressing warning helps in your case?

Comment: `df = df.copy()` works

Comment: But why do I need to make a copy first?

Comment: In Pandas, indexing a DataFrame returns a reference to the initial DataFrame. Thus, changing the subset will change the initial DataFrame. Thus, you'd want to use the copy if you want to make sure the initial DataFrame shouldn't change.

Comment: But int my case, I want to alter the original DataFrame

Comment: Yes, you do alter. But you're also indexing specific columns to choose the values from. Take a look here for elaborated description https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html